# Print "for loop" data after ending loop

Tags: python

After ending the for loop , how do i use the output from that loop? 
Essentially , i would like the last **print(url)** command to give the same output as the **print(url)** command in the **for loop**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', class_="mw-category-group")

url = []
for c in links:
    b = c.find_all('a')
    for a in b:
        u = a.get('href')
        url = "https://dota2.gamepedia.com" + u
        # print("https://dota2.gamepedia.com" + u)
        # print(url)

print(url)
```

Comment: It will print the value of `url` at that point in the code.  As best I can see by eye, this *is* the last value you would print within the loop.  You neglected to finish your post, so we're not sure what is the discrepancy.  See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Would you mind restating your question? As the code appears, it should do exactly what you are asking. Every time 'url = "https://dota2.gamepedia.com" + u' runs, it will update the value of url to point to the new value.

Can you show us what the last 'print(url)' is actually displaying?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness of this question. I am a new programmer. I dont know how to ask programming questions. I fear this clarification(below) wont help either. but ill give it a shot anyhow :) .

The print(url) in the loop gives out all the urls. The print(url) after the loop gives only the last url , whereas i would like it to give it all the urls aswell. ( i want to carry out further functions on that data , and dont want to do it in the loop).

Answer (score 0):

so i can see you should add your url variable to list which has the same name (it's not correct)

```
for a in b:
    u = a.get('href')
    url = "https://dota2.gamepedia.com" + u 
    url.append(url)
```

print(url)

but consider changing the naming of your variable like you have a,b,u,c you could name it like anchor, link to make easier to read for you and a specially to someone else